# Un-expected result from RSpec change on `destroy` object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to test `destroy` on my model:

```
   subject(:product){ FactoryGirl.create(:product)}

    it "destroys product" do
      expect{product.destroy}.to change(Product,:count).by(-1)
    end
```

But it fails. Can any one point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `subject` block is evaluated lazily. That means the product is created when it is first used. There is no change at all because you call `product` for the first time in the expectation and immediately destroy that record.

To solve this problem ensure that the record gets created before the expectation:

```
subject(:product) { FactoryGirl.create(:product) }

before { product } # this line creates the product before running the test

it 'destroys product' do
  expect { product.destroy }.to change(Product, :count).by(-1)
end
```

Or:

```
subject!(:product) { FactoryGirl.create(:product) } # note the '!'

it 'destroys product' do
  expect { product.destroy }.to change(Product, :count).by(-1)
end
```